# Video Colors are washed out in Qt

Tags: qt, qml, color-space

I'm using Qt 5.15 on Windows, and I'm facing an issue with the MediaPlayer and VideoOutput components in QML. When playing a video, the colors appear pale and washed out, not as expected.

Here are the details of the video: "Video: MPEG4 Video (H264) 9300x606 30fps 51614kbps [V: Mainconcept Video Media Handler [eng] (h264 main L5.1, yuv420p, 9300x606, 51614 kb/s)]".

I'm wondering if there's an issue with the color space. Should I consider adding a shader to convert it to RGB, and if so, why would that be necessary? Alternatively, should I convert the video codec?

Here's an example of how colors are washed out. Right is the original video, left is the video played using MediaPlayer

[example img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuOpy.jpg)

you can download this test video from https://www.pexels.com/video/close-up-of-a-person-working-with-futuristic-laboratory-equipment-12202017/

Here's the code example

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtMultimedia 5.15

Item {
    id: idRoot
    width: 4096
    height: 2160

    MediaPlayer {
        id: idMediaPlayer
        playbackRate: 0
        source: "../assets/test2.mp4"
        videoOutput: idVideoOutput
        autoPlay: true
        loops: MediaPlayer.Infinite
    }


    VideoOutput {
        id: idVideoOutput
        width: idRoot.width
        height: idRoot.height
        fillMode: VideoOutput.PreserveAspectCrop
        source: idMediaPlayer
        autoOrientation: false
        flushMode: VideoOutput.FirstFrame
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be useful to include a screenshot in your question of the video (original and pale version). A code example, including a link to an example video may be useful too to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @m7913d i just added an example and the code

Comment: It is possible your specific codec is not fully supported. You will have to transcode your video (e.g. handbrake, ffmpeg, etc.)

Comment: @StephenQuan could you explain more how to transcode my video? or how to use ffmpeg in qt

Comment: I mean transcode/convert your video in a 3rd party application. Expect the codec support in Qt to be baseline, so, even though MP4 is supported, not all types of MP4 are supported, The suggestion really is asking you to do some preprocessing of your MP4 and use the final result in your Qt application.

Comment: Have the colours really been 'washed out'.  To me it looks like nothing more than something like a basic gamma correction occurring somewhere along the line.  Can't be certain though.